# CSS Flexbox Display Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

It is kind of tricky situation I am in now.

I have two `templates` that need to be displayed `based on ng-switch` like:

```
    <div class="summary-card" ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
        <div ng-switch ="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
            <div ng-switch-when=true>
                <div style="background-color: #ccc !important;">
                    11111 my custom div
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-title" style="text-align: left;" id="{{cardData.label}}">{{cardData.label}}</div>
                    <div class="card-data">
                       .....
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, `the first div when ng-switch is set to true` **needs to be aligned side by side with the others** `that get generated by ng-repeat`.

something like a `css-grid`.

[image]

The problem is `<div class="summary-card"` that sets the items to `display flex`. **I cannot modify or change it but I only need this style for the divs generated by ng-repeat.**

But now it gets applied to all the divs, like:

```
div.summary-card {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 10px 15px 0px;

        display: flex;
}
```

[image]

How can I fix the same?

Answer (score 0):

you should follow dom structure like this

```html
<div class="summary-card">
  <div>
    <div style="background-color: #ccc !important;">
      11111 my custom div
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cool-grid">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title" style="text-align: left;">{{cardData.label}}</div>
      <div class="card-data">
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title" style="text-align: left;">{{cardData.label}}</div>
      <div class="card-data">
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title" style="text-align: left;">{{cardData.label}}</div>
      <div class="card-data">
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-title" style="text-align: left;">{{cardData.label}}</div>
      <div class="card-data">
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your css should be something like

```css
.summary-card {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px
}

.cool-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

check this out :- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzomoN

This is not the complete answer but it will give you some idea

you can also use grid layout if you want

```css
.summary-card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-coloumn-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.cool-grid {
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-coloumn-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  display: inline-grid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```