# How to apply a class in css while working with ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I know it's silly but I can't figure it out. In my template,

```
    <div class="summary-card" ng-repeat="cardData in summaryCardsCtrl.summaryDetails">
        <div ng-switch ="cardData.uniqueCardsDataFlag">
            <div ng-switch-when=true>
                <div ng-include="'src/templates/my-unique-card.html'"></div>      
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <div  ng-include="'src/templates/my-analytics-card.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

`summary-card` class gets added to all the divs.
The generated HTML looks like:

[image]

But somehow, for the last 3 divs `that get generated by ng-switch-default block`, I want a `wrapped div to be added like`:

[image]

I know `this is kind of against the odds but the design needs the same.`

Please help.

The last 3 divs get generated by `ng-switch-default`.

Is there anything we can add to achieve the same?

Comment: You could achieve this by separating `summaryDetails` into two different arrays, one with items that have `uniqueCardsDataFlag = true` and another with `uniqueCardsDataFlag = false`.  Then do two ng-repeats, the 2nd one wrapped with the `display:flex;` div and get rid of the `ng-switch`.

Comment: Can you use the [`$first` special property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview)?

Comment: `display:flex;` is style, not a class.

Comment: @georgeawg That will only work if he knows his `ng-switch-default` block is always triggered by the first element.

Comment: @georgeawg Actually a wrapper div with no class also do.

Comment: @BShaps look at the OPs previous questions -- [display: flex not working in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237812/display-flex-not-working-in-css) and [CSS Flexbox Display Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232263/css-flexbox-display-issue).

Comment: @georgeawg While he may have indicated that fact in previous questions, he didn't here so that assumption should not be made IMO. If it is still the case that the first div will always be the only `true` value then he shouldn't even be using `ng-switch` and should use `ng-if` on the `$index`